# Check Query for DateTime being X seconds ago

Tags: php

I am using PHP and MySQL to create a flood-filter for my forums I've recently created and I did research this, but little results came and only one of them potentially brought me further to my resolution.

This is the code

```
$overview_threads = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `forum_posts` WHERE `author`='".$_SESSION['username']."' AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `created`, now()) <= 20");
```

The code is made in attempt to select a thread made by the user within an interval of 20 seconds or less and then do an if statement to prevent the user of posting within that time.

What do I do for this?

Comment: So is your question about the query or how to read the data from the query result set?

Comment: My question is on getting a result of the query to see if it is 1, and if it is one, it will redirect, thus not posting the forum post. The part of the 20 second interval is not working.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should probably use `DATE_SUB()` for this as it will be much more index friendly (you need an index on `created` of course)

```
SELECT * FROM `forum_posts`
WHERE `author` = ?
AND `created` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 SECONDS)
```

Second, in order to determine if you have a record, you will have to look at the result set.

```
$result = mysql_query($query); // query is that shown above
if (false === $result) {
    echo mysql_error();
} else if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   // you found a match
}
```

Third, you should really look at using `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_*` functions, as these are deprecated.

Comment: Just a quick question, does the code you post above get a result if the 'created' field is longer than 20 seconds or less than 20 seconds?

Comment: @user2230442 It gets any result where `created` is greater than or equal to 20 seconds ago.

Comment: Can it be made to get the result where the 'created' is 20 seconds or less by just switching the greater than signs?

Comment: @user2230442 Yes, but that would not get you what you are looking for that would get you posts older than 20 seconds ago.

Comment: Wait, can I make myself more clear? I am trying to create a basic system that finds any thread made by the user (with session) so that it blocks or continues depending on the result. Are you telling me by using your first answer, this will work for that purpose?

Comment: @user2230442 Yes I understand your logic to be that if the user had a post that was created within the last 20 seconds, you want to do something different (prevent the entry of a new post presumably).  That query will select all posts from that user that have happened within the last 20 seconds from the current database system time. You count the number of rows returned from the query to determine if there are any such posts meeting the criteria.

Comment: @user2230442 So say that a user has a post with `created` value of `2013-05-08 12:00:00` and say the current system time returned by `NOW()` is `2013-05-08 12:00:10`. In this case, the last WHERE condition in this query would effectively be `AND created >= '2013-05-08 11:59:50'` (the subtraction of a 20 second interval from current time).  This row would of course be returned in the result set in this case since `2013-05-08 12:00:00` > `2013-05-08 11:59:50`

Comment: I wish I can test this, but the result turns out to be a Boolean error and causes an output, preventing redirections and only header errors.

Comment: @user2230442 So what error do you get from mysql_error()? (see my updated code for basic error handling suggestion)

Comment: The way the AddPost function works is it inserts everything into the queries and uses header() to redirect the user to the newest thread they have created. When the result is false, it creates output, ruining the header redirect.

Comment: @user2230442 The result should only be false if there is an actual MySQL error, in which case you should investigate what that error is.  I just showed an `echo` statement here for convenience you can obviously just log the error if you don't want output associated with it.